# Finding a specific malware sample for malware analysis purposes

Tags: malware, virus

I wish to analyze the changes made by a specific virus. For example, Win32.Sality.
Where can I get the sample of this, or other similar, malware for testing?

Comment: And do AV editors in general have some official feed for malware?

Comment: +1, always wondered this: where is malware when you need it?!

Comment: I'm sure you can find some scene websites with virus samples, I can't remember the title exactly but there was one talk at Chaos Comm. Conference who was talking about that. Alternatively I can just give you my old hard drive ;)

Comment: @val you seem to be under the impression theres a complete collection of all viruses ever somewhere? AV vendors might have something like that but the storage requirements would be intense. Regardless your wont be getting a copy from anyone. Also. Ecair test file?

Comment: Can you say me which tools you are using for the analyze?

Answer (score 9):

[Contagiodump](http://contagiodump.blogspot.com.es/) blog and the spam folder are your best friends

Comment: Would be the first time ever that my spam folder contains malware.

Answer (score 8):

`http://www.offensivecomputing.net` has about 4,456,929 samples.

**UPDATE**

Offensive Computing is now offline

Answer (score 6):

http://www.malware.lu/ Has 2,236,674 samples

Answer (score 3):

[You](http://www.honeynet.org/) [can](http://dionaea.carnivore.it/) [always](http://glastopf.org/) run [your](http://hihat.sourceforge.net/) own [honeypot](http://code.google.com/p/kippo/).

Answer (score 3):

[virusshare.com](http://www.virusshare.com) is another great repository of malware samples, having a huge number of samples. A snapshot from the website's homepage:

[image]

Access is by invitation only, so you will need to drop a mail to the site admin.

Another good resource that I know of- [www.deependresearch.org](http://www.deependresearch.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Here Are Some List of sites where you can get malware for samples

[Contagio](http://contagiodump.blogspot.com/)

`KernelMode.info`

`DamageLab.org`

`MalwareBlacklist`

[Malware.lu](http://malware.lu/)

`Malware URLs`.

`Open Malware`

[virusshare](http://virusshare.com/)

`An Blog which has some url's`

[Malshare](http://www.malshare.com)

[Tekdefence](http://www.tekdefense.com/downloads/)

`MalwareTIps` - Virus exchange Forum

The above url's are An Summary from [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/206/where-can-i-as-an-individual-get-malware-samples-to-analyze)

Comment: Tekdefence is the only simply browsed. Openmalvare responds with some list if I enter "windows" into the search windows. I would not find these sites without your help. This trick, with entering "windows" into MD5 window, however, does not succeed with Malshare. It seems really demanding exact MD5 keys, which I do not have without having samples first.

Answer (score 0):

[Github](https://github.com/ytisf/theZoo/tree/master/malwares/Binaries) now contains massive repos of malware. The one I linked is but an example.