# Free collection of virus test samples

Tags: virus

You want to check functionality of your antivirus. [virussign.com](http://www.virussign.com/) can do that for money. Is there a free virus base?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding Win32.Sality sample for malware analysis purposes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18875/finding-win32-sality-sample-for-malware-analysis-purposes)

Comment: @AviD, At first, being off-topic and being duplicate is two different things. Secondly, the recommended question has got +8 positive votes. That is why, I guess, the people who closed this topic for all sorts of nonsense reasons blamed on me have not raised this issue. Thanks for doing that. Third, the "original" question asks for specific sample. It must be closed as "too localized" rather than cover query for generic samples. Otherwise explain what my question has to do with Sality. Finally, my question is definitely clear an even has got the answer and, thus, closed under false reason.

Comment: That user did not want the virus database. He wanted Win32.Sality only. How can you make it "more constructive"? By broadening its scope, you change the content what user was looking for, not the "form". Because he may fail to find his specific virus in general database. Ok? Previously, you have given reason of duplicate. Thanks for saying that reason for why you close the questions do not matter for you. I appreciate that.